# How does statsmodels estimate standard errors of paramters?

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, statsmodels

I cannot find any specification in the documentation on how OLS estimates the standard errors in statsmodels

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = ... # some pandas.DataFrame with a Y-column
regressors = data.drop(columns=['Y'])
dependant_variable = data['Y']
ols = sm.OLS(dependant_variable, regressors)
result = ols.fit()
print(f"Statmodels get standard error {result.bse}")
```

What algorithm do they use to compute the standard errors in question, and what statistical assumptions do they make?

Can I incorporate assumptions, such as homoscedacity or known error variance?

Comment: The default standard errors assume homoskedasticity with unknown residual variance, which is estimated.  You can pass options to generate standard errors allowing for heteroskedasticity, heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation, or clustering. The latter two require additional inputs.

Comment: That is nice to know. I've also found the `HC#_se` properties, so that is good. Is there any explanation of this in the documentation? I've tried to read the source code, but it is a bit difficult to get into. The reason I ask is that I get a slightly different s.e. when doing the computations manually myself.

Comment: These names follow Stata's nomenclature which I think matches MacKinnon and White. https://www.stata.com/manuals/rregress.pdf